# How to focus on input after power-select-multiple is rendered?

Tags: ember.js

I want to be able to search right after the webpage is rendered, instead of click on the search box then start typing.
However when I trying to mimic `focusInput` in original source code, it doesn't work.

It could be reproduced by visit 
https://ember-power-select.com/docs/multiple-selection
and run `document.querySelector('.ember-power-select-trigger-multiple-input').focus()` which is focus on an `input` tag.

I expected to see something like this
[image: screen shot 2018-02-28 at 1 44 06 pm]

, but actually nothing happened.

I also tried to `.click()` on all parent html elements of that `input`, but nothing happened

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [a tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) to you. When you set the tabindex to 1 the search field will be the first to focus.

As an alternative you can try to achive this with an [application instance initializer](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/applications/initializers/). In it you can now select the proper element and set the focus on it.